# Cannot refresh scene/Nodes in JavaFX when update

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX. I try to program a simple GUI but I face those problem whom might be related.
I set files with a File Chooser and want to do pretty basic operations:

1. save the last folder used
2. write the name of the selected file in the VBox

Here's my code (which compiles):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static Stage primaryStageS;
    public static Scene mainScene;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene((new Test(primaryStage).getScene()));
        primaryStageS = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("Parcel Manager Main Page");
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        VBox main = new VBox(new Label("Test program"));
        mainScene = new Scene(main, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene((new Test(primaryStage)).getScene());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public class Object1 {
        String name;

        public Object1(File f) throws IOException {
            name = f.getName();
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public class Test {
        Object1 collec;
        String collecName;
        File lastFolder;
        Pane rootGroup;

        public Test(Stage stage) {
            setButtons(stage);
        }

        public void setButtons(Stage stageGoal) {
            VBox vbox = new VBox();
            Button b = getButton(stageGoal);
            vbox.getChildren().addAll(b, new Label(getCollecName() == null ? "no name" : collecName));
            final GridPane inputGridPane = new GridPane();
            GridPane.setConstraints(vbox, 0, 0);
            inputGridPane.getChildren().addAll(vbox);
            rootGroup = new VBox(12);
            rootGroup.getChildren().addAll(inputGridPane);
            rootGroup.setPadding(new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));
        }

        public Button getButton(Stage stage) {
            FileChooser fileChooserParcel = new FileChooser();
            fileChooserParcel.setInitialDirectory(getLastFolder());
            Button button = new Button("Select a File");
            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                File f = fileChooserParcel.showOpenDialog(stage);
                if (f != null) {
                    try {
                        collec = new Object1(f);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    setLastFolder(f.getParentFile());
                    setCollecName(collec);
                    setButtons(stage); // tried to reload every buttons - doesn't work
                    stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth() + 0.0001); // found this dirty hack but doesn't work
                }
            });
            return button;
        }

        public void setCollecName(Object1 o1) {
            collecName = o1.getName();
        }

        public String getCollecName() {
            return collecName;
        }

        public File getLastFolder() {
            return lastFolder;
        }

        public void setLastFolder(File folder) {
            System.out.println("set last folder: " + folder);
            lastFolder = folder;
        }

        private Scene getScene() {
            return new Scene(rootGroup, 800, 600);
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot refresh the Nodes, either to set a current Initial Directory or display the *collecName* on the VBox. I tried to regenerate them with reloading of objects or resizing the window, but nothing works. When I print the variables on console, I see that they changes. But haven't found any refresh method for any of my objects.

I bet it's a design program issue, but I have been moving things around for the last week and doesn't know how to fix this.

Thanks !

Comment: about to request a [mcve] - before scrolling to the end ;) looks nearly standalone except access to App/ImportObject - please re-write the example to not access external code (don't add anything) - and it should be compileable (a real java file, with header, imports, and without anything unrelated and no dots ..

Comment: Why is this line `primaryStage.setScene((new Test(primaryStage).getScene()));` duplicated? I also have a bit of a problem with your `getScene()` function returning a new `Scene` object every time it is invoked. Seems like a wasteful (inefficient) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the initial directory once. I guess you want to set it every time you click the `button`. So move that line of code to inside the handler.

Compare the below `getButton()` method with yours.

```java
public Button getButton(Stage stage) {
    FileChooser fileChooserParcel = new FileChooser();
    Button button = new Button("Select a File");
    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        fileChooserParcel.setInitialDirectory(getLastFolder()); // CHANGE HERE.
        File f = fileChooserParcel.showOpenDialog(stage);
        if (f != null) {
            try {
                collec = new Object1(f);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            setLastFolder(f.getParentFile());
            setCollecName(collec);
            setButtons(stage); // tried to reload every buttons - doesn't work
            stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth() + 0.0001); // found this dirty hack but doesn't work
        }
    });
    return button;
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the tip ! Yep that works. I tried to do a similar thing to update text with the setButtons(stage); or stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth() + 0.0001); but text doesn't change/refresh in those cases. So the inner problem's still here. Why elements aren't refreshing? Is it necessary to declare listeners on the values ?